The Class.forName method caches the class in the initiating classloader, whereas ClassLoader.loadClass does not
As the title described, is it intended to do so?

Classloader. loadClass () Caches the loaded class object and returns always the same class object

This is done by the defining classloader
This ensures that each classloader loads the same class only once



Class.forName () calls the normal classloader hierarchy to load the class (same happens as above)

But caches the class object within the initiating classloader
In standard cases no problem but can be tricky in dynamic environments



ref

if so, does it violet the jvm specification?

5.3.2. Loading Using a User-defined Class Loader
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-5.html


The following steps are used to load and thereby create the nonarray class or interface C denoted by N using a user-defined class loader L.
First, the Java Virtual Machine determines whether L has already been recorded as an initiating loader of a class or interface denoted by N. If so, this class or interface is C, and no class creation is necessary.
Otherwise, the Java Virtual Machine invokes loadClass(N) on L. The value returned by the invocation is the created class or interface C. The Java Virtual Machine then records that L is an initiating loader of C (§5.3.4). The remainder of this section describes this process in more detail.


@apangin needs help

Don’t post links to images of text. Include the text, most notably the statements your question is about. Besides that, how could the behavior of methods (regardless of whether the description is correct) be a violation of a specification about how the JVM resolves classes? Does the red color of tomatoes violate a specification that mandates that cucumbers are green?

@Holger The JVM specification defines the guidelines to be followed during the class resolution process, which should be adhered to when implementing the JVM. The implementation of Class.forName follows the JVM specification by recording the relationship between the initiating loader and the loaded class, so that it can quickly identify the already loaded class upon subsequent loads. However, ClassLoader.loadClass does not adhere to this specification; it still follows the parent delegation logic each time, re-checking rather than directly fetching from the cache.

The implementation of Class.forName does not follow the JVM specification, as the JVM specification applies to the JVM and only the JVM. A specification for X does not apply to Y. The method Class.forName is not the JVM. The method Class.forName has it’s own specification which doesn’t say anything about caching. And again, include the text of the claim, including a reference to the source, instead of a link to a screenshot. The, we can discuss about the validity of the text

You have to understand that a ClassLoader implementation and the JVM are distinct entities and it’s not the duty of the ClassLoader to implement the JVM’s linking. Back in the days of Java 1.0, the responsibilities were not that separated but I would expect a presentation from 2008 to know better.
The very section you have already cited says below the cited part:

Since JDK release 1.1, Oracle’s Java Virtual Machine implementation has invoked the loadClass method of a class loader in order to cause it to load a class or interface. The argument to loadClass is the name of the class or interface to be loaded. There is also a two-argument version of the loadClass method, where the second argument is a boolean that indicates whether the class or interface is to be linked or not. Only the two-argument version was supplied in JDK release 1.0.2, and Oracle’s Java Virtual Machine implementation relied on it to link the loaded class or interface. From JDK release 1.1 onward, Oracle’s Java Virtual Machine implementation links the class or interface directly, without relying on the class loader.

So the linking is the JVM’s job and that’s how you have to read the preceding part

Otherwise, the Java Virtual Machine invokes loadClass(N) on L. The value returned by the invocation is the created class or interface C. The Java Virtual Machine then records that L is an initiating loader of C (§5.3.4).

emphasis by me
So, after the loadClass method returned a class, however the loader implementation retrieved it, the JVM will record the loader as an initiating loader of the class, in its own data structure(s).
Once you have realized that it is a JVM internal data structure holding the information about initiating loaders, you may see the even earlier statement in a new light:

First, the Java Virtual Machine determines whether L has already been recorded as an initiating loader of a class or interface denoted by N. If so, this class or interface is C, and no class creation is necessary.

Since this is a JVM internal step, it implies that it won’t invoke the loadClass method again, if the class loader is already known to be an initiating loader of a class of that name.
So, as long as a single class loading context is concerned, a class loader’s failure to return the same Class object for the same name wouldn’t be noticed at all, as the method won’t get invoked twice. Not to speak of the fact that a single class loader can’t define two classes of the same name, as the defineClass method would reject it.
But you can have multiple class loaders delegating to each other in an inconsistent way (this does not mean the parent delegation, which is a consistent one). And for this specific case, the JVM specification says:

… To enforce these constraints, the Java Virtual Machine will, at certain prescribed times (see §5.3.1, §5.3.2, §5.3.3, and §5.3.5), record that a particular loader is an initiating loader of a particular class. After recording that a loader is an initiating loader of a class, the Java Virtual Machine must immediately check to see if any loading constraints are violated. If so, the record is retracted, the Java Virtual Machine throws a LinkageError, and the loading operation that caused the recording to take place fails.

This illustrates that the ClassLoader is not part of the JVM but rather something that is distrusted by the JVM at some point. The JVM itself will enforce the constraints by throwing a LinkageError if the constraints are violated. This does not preclude delegation, but the delegation has to be consistent. The validity of delegation is even stated in the same cited section:


The class loader L can delegate the loading of C to some other class loader L'. This is accomplished by passing the argument N directly or indirectly to an invocation of a method on L' (typically the loadClass method). The result of the invocation is C.



The statement about Class.forName caching the class in the initiating loader is just wrong. Since Class.forName is never invoked by the JVM’s linker, there is no initiating loader. The closest, you get, is the caller’s class loader:
Class.forName:

Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to:
Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)

where currentLoader denotes the defining class loader of the current class.

So this method is special in using the caller’s class loader, however, it will end up at that loader’s loadClass method if the class loader is not null. If the caller’s loader uses delegation, it’s still possible that the class is cached at a defining loader different from the caller’s loader.
